# AFwall+ doesn't work on restricted user

Tags: applications, firewall

I installed AFwall+ as admin with a rooted device & it works very well; but I created a restricted user now & this AFwall+ is not working in user, any tip?

Comment: Try enabling "dual user" support from experimental.

Comment: where is this "dual support" located??

Comment: Under Preferences > Experimental > Dual App Support.